# SQL Server datafile growths

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For SQL Server 2008 what is the maximum number of growths?  And which view do I query to find that information for a datafile in my database?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of growths depends on the autogrowth settings for the file in question.  If you set it to unlimited then there is no maximum number of growths.  If you set a limit for growth on your files then it will be dependent on how much you set your file to grow by for each autogrowth.

There is no view to see autogrowth events.  In order to see autogrow events you'll need to inspect the SQL logs, have a trace running that captures autogrowth events or use event notifications.  You can also right-click on the database, choose Reports | Standard Reports | Disk Usage and look for AutoGrow events.